# Plot wind speed and direction from u, v components

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot the wind speed and direction, but there is an error code that keeps telling me that "sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32." Here is the code that I am using:

```
N = 500
ws = np.array(u)
wd = np.array(v)


df = pd.DataFrame({'direction': [ws], 'speed': [wd]})
df
direction   speed
0   [[-7.87291, -8.19969, -8.41213, -8.42775, -8.4...   [[-3.68055, -4.07912, -4.07992, -3.55594, -3.2...
from windrose import plot_windrose


N = 500
ws = np.random.random(u) * 6
wd = np.random.random(v) * 360
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': ws, 'direction': wd})
plot_windrose(df, kind='contour', bins=np.arange(0.01,8,1), cmap=cm.hot, lw=3)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-dfb188ec377a> in <module>()
1 from windrose import plot_windrose
2 N = 500
3 ws = np.random.random(u) * 6
4 wd = np.random.random(v) * 360
5 df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': ws, 'direction': wd})

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.random_sample      (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:10396)()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.cont0_array (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:1865)()

ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32
```

How do I fix this and plot the U and V? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot wind U, V use `barbs` and `quiver`. Look at the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
d = np.arctan(Y ** 2. - .25 * Y - X)
U, V = 5 * np.cos(d), np.sin(d)
# barbs plot
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.barbs(X, Y, U, V)
#quiver plot
ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
qui = ax2.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
plt.quiverkey(qui, 0.9, 1.05, 1, '1 m/s',labelpos='E',fontproperties={'weight': 'bold'})

plt.show()
```

[image]