# Plotting wind direction

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot wind direction data using the following method:

```
wind_direction=(270-(numpy.arctan2(V,U)* (180/numpy.pi)))
print (wind_direction)
X,Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, x)
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.barbs(U, V)

ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
qui = ax2.quiver(V, U)
plt.quiverkey(qui, 0.9, 1.05, 1, '1 m/s',labelpos='E',fontproperties= {'weight': 'bold'})

plt.show
```

ɪ am using the example provided in this linkː

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626726/9913654

My out put is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0VIK.jpg), however, I'd like my output to be similar to the one provided in the link above. A snapshot of their graph isː
My converted wind direction data isː[333.59395428 329.32182958 331.04899611 ... 383.11285388 376.09828775
 339.25266619]

This may be an easy question but I am new to Python. Also I am receiving errors, help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: @Serenity ɪ adapted your code into my work, would it be possible to generate my code to generate a similar graphʔ Thank you